# ASPNETCore API ExceptionFilterAttribute and IStringLocalizer

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, localization

I have a ExceptionFilterAttribute in my ASPNETCore API where I handle certain exception types.

For example any UnauthorizedAccessException I return HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, any KeyNotFoundException I return HttpStatusCode.NotFound etc.

However, I'm also returning a basic message. For example, the string "Key Not Found" is returned with the HttpStatusCode.NotFound.

I would like the messages contained in the ExceptionFilterAttribute to be parsed using the IStringLocalizer. However, a ExceptionFilterAttribute doesn't seem to support dependency injection.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Is there an approach here which is considered best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `IServiceProvider` from the `ExceptionContext`.

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    var service = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<MyService>();
}
```